# find_element() with Link_Text not working using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, linktext

I am new to selenium whenever I try to find elements using `id`, `name` , `xpath` or anything it gives the same error

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get('https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/selenium-safaridriver-macos/')
driver.find_element(By.Link_Text,'Webinar' )
```

It shows error by underlining By.
I tried writing

```
driver.find_element_by_id('Webinar')
```

But it does not go through I tried different websites and with different elements like class, id but seems like there is a problem with finding elements by any method is there something that needs to installed to make it work?

Comment: I know it's a crazy question, but did you import the `By` class?

Answer (score 1):

You have to take care of a couple of things here:

- The supported [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) should be ***`LINK_TEXT`*** instead of `Link_Text`
- The *link_text* should be ***`Webinars`*** instead of `Webinar`.
- Effectively, your line of code should be:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Webinars' )
  ```

However, within the [webpage](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/selenium-safaridriver-macos/) there are multiple elements with *`innerText`* as ***`Webinars`***. So you need to use a [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) which identifies the element uniquely within the DOM.

---

### Solution

Ideally, to locate the **clickable** element from the *menu container* with text as ***`Webinars`*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.menu-menu-1-container a[href='https://www.lambdatest.com/webinar/']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='menu-menu-1-container']//a[text()='Webinars']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Most `find_element_by_*("text")` is now  removed from selenium  as of version 4.5, replaced by `find_element(By.*,"text")`

Answer (score 0):

This

```
driver.find_element(By.Link_Text,'Webinar')
```

should be

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Webinar')
```

Also, Import this `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

If you are on Selenium4 then you should not really use:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('Webinar')
```

use this instead:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'Webinar')
```

If you take a look at the source code, you'd see:

```
class By(object):
    """
    Set of supported locator strategies.
    """

    ID = "id"
    XPATH = "xpath"
    LINK_TEXT = "link text"
    PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
    NAME = "name"
    TAG_NAME = "tag name"
    CLASS_NAME = "class name"
    CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
```

Comment: Are you sure `driver.find_element_('Webinar')` will work? assuming you remove the trailing `_`, `'Webinar'` will populate the `by` parameter, not the value.

Comment: @Guy: thnx man! It was my bad, typo :(

Comment: @cruisepandey thanks for help tried using this way earlier also but did not worked for me I know sounds crazy why it doesn't work at my end it gives error NameError: name 'By' is not defined and yeah i am using selenium 4.1 on mac